# Event Viewer - Add custom Event Data Attribute with C#

Tags: c#, events, logging

I'm trying to add a Name attribute in the `EventData` (Windows Logs) in C#, like the one from the image below:

[image]

```
EventLog.WriteEntry(_moduleConfiguration.DestinationEventSource, errorMessage, EventLogEntryType.Error);
```

Above code doesn't have an option to add that name attribute.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: You can find a step by step guide here: [Writing to the event log in .NET - the right way](http://blog.dlgordon.com/2012/06/writing-to-event-log-in-net-right-way.html)

Comment: You may also want to take a look at this article and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2007/april/event-tracing-improve-debugging-and-performance-tuning-with-etw) docs article and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/defining-event-data-templates) one.

Comment: I guess, that you'll need to create an [`instrumentation manifest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/writing-an-instrumentation-manifest) for that and define an [`event data template`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/defining-event-data-templates) for that

Comment: The link in the first comments contain all the required step to create, compile and register the manifest. But It's too broad for an answer here and I'm not sure if it's a good idea to lift all the steps and codes from the external source and put it here.